# How do concepts of User (UserAccount) and Realm relate in Apache Shiro?

Tags: java, shiro

I'm reading up on [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) and like to see if I got this mental model right.

> From the [docs](http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html): "A `Realm` is a component that can access application-specific security data such as `users`, `roles`, and `permissions`". .. "Realms usually have a 1-to-1 correlation with a data source such as a relational database, LDAP directory, file system, or other similar resource. "

Moreover, I've read that an `application` may include multiple `realms` for its authentication and authorization purposes.

Ok so great, but how do this `Realms` relate to the concept of a User?

- is every `Realm` expected to be a partition over the user-space? I.e: a `User` may only ever occur in 1 `Realm`
- or, and this is what I'm expecting, `Realms` can be used to layer authentication & authorization on top of eachother and *may* work on the same `User`. However in that case, where is the `User` managed? It should be somewhere external to a `Realm` I guess, but where?

Perhaps I'm confused by this because I'm thinking of `User` as a single entity (e.g: of me there can be only one) . And should instead be thinking of `User` as a `UserAccount`. I.e.: Each `Realm` manages it's own `Useraccounts` (in the docs called `User`), but a `User` may have multiple `UserAcounts`. Is that correct?

Assuming the above is correct:

- is there any logic that enables me to query for all `UserAccounts` of a given User? I.e: basically merging all `Useraccounts` together to get a complete view of the `User`?
- does the concept of `User` in this case (1 `User` possibly having multiple `UserAccounts`) even exist in Shiro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define relation between `Realms` in `authenticationStrategy`. Lets see the example. User will be authenticated only when he passes authentication against all realms. You can make your own authenticationStrategy implementation which says just one successful authentication is enough or whatsoever.

In the example, we combine JDBC realm to store users names (no passwords) and authenticate it against LDAP.

Lets say you will add one another LDAP realm and create authenticationStrategy, where not all authentications against realm are needed. But just one successful authentication against LDAP is enough.

#### shiro.ini

```
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
ds.resourceName = java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx

noPassWordCredentialMatcher = eu.corp.domain.auth.NoPassMatcher

ldapRealm = eu.corp.domain.auth.CustomActiveDirectoryRealm
ldapRealm.searchBase = OU=USERS,OU=EN,DC=our,DC=corp
ldapRealm.url = ldap://our.corp:389
ldapRealm.principalSuffix = @our.corp

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $noPassWordCredentialMatcher

jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT name FROM auth WHERE name = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role.shortcut FROM auth LEFT JOIN auth_role ON auth_role.auth_id = auth.id LEFT JOIN role ON role.id = auth_role.role_id WHERE auth.name = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT permission.shortcut FROM role JOIN role_permission ON role_permission.role_id = role.id JOIN permission ON permission.id = role_permission.permission_id WHERE role.shortcut = ?

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

securityManager.realms = $ldapRealm, $jdbcRealm
authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AllSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy
```

Comment: Shouldn't this example use the FirstSuccessfulStrategy instead of the AllSuccessfulStrategy?

Comment: The intention was to grant access only to users in project DB and also reuse company wide LDAP authentification. So, thats why jdbcRealm have noPassWordCredentialMatcher.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So the no password matcher just checks that the user ID exists in the DB and returns the appropriate result. Makes sense.

Comment: You could use the standard `org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.AllowAllCredentialsMatcher` as the credential matcher as well. It allows all credentials but expects at least a username so that means the authentication query should return a value. If it doesn't it won't match, so in this config it will only pass if the name is found in the auth table.