# Apache shiro: Use ldap for user authentication and database for roles/permissions?

Tags: jdbc, ldap, shiro, mixed

we just started with apache shiro and it works fine in a simple jdbc or ldap based environment.

Be our requirements are the following:

- Authentication of the users agains a ldap server
- Roles+Permissions should be stored inside a database

Has anyone some pointers on how this can be done?

Comment: Looks like this is what we need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124192/how-do-concepts-of-user-useraccount-and-realm-relate-in-apache-shiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different question but the example is exactly what you looking for.

[How do concepts of User (UserAccount) and Realm relate in Apache Shiro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124192/how-do-concepts-of-user-useraccount-and-realm-relate-in-apache-shiro/19176762#19176762)